# Skip Bitbucket API if not accessible gradle Go

Tags: go, gradle

I am trying to build the gradle project with go language.

While building my project, I am facing following issue whose stacktrace is as follows :

```
xecution failed for task ':resolveBuildDependencies'.   
> Exception in resolution, message is:  
  Cannot resolve dependency:github.com/hashicorp/vic: commit='LATEST_COMMIT', urls=[https://github.com/hashicorp/vic.git, git@github.com:hashicorp/vic.git] 
  Resolution stack is:  
  +- github.com/streamsets/datacollector-edge   
   +- github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl#1e8e50f4f86c755c1a1147a929d9d51058f3bd1d  
    +- google.golang.org/grpc#b2ba77a36ff809ab344b98368d9ecc3e12f943d6  
     +- github.com/envoyproxy/go-control-plane#b51f8451dc7f3038dc909ad7fd5e12f58c0f3fb3 
      +- k8s.io/apimachinery#74be3b88bedbf44de881c8c33c5b1c3c536ad1f4   
       +- k8s.io/klog#f8e668dbaa5f6f0e6a5c24ffd7667263840d79ae  
        +- golang.org/x/exp#a2d0902c3ac7d8a588083a4600140f244aefee16    
         +- github.com/go-kit/kit#ab98ef03f368227b016c95423ee291c9812cae64  
          +- github.com/hashicorp/consul#bffdce7c1e2ffc3b7c753b506cd68c685a6a19d9   
           +- github.com/hashicorp/go-discover#c573d69da192ae69d5386b65b64353832677aad8 
* Try:  
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.   
* Exception is: 
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':resolveBuildDependencies'. 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:96)    
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:65)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ActionEventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(ActionEventFiringTaskExecuter.java:44) 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TimeoutTaskExecuter.execute(TimeoutTaskExecuter.java:53) 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SnapshotAfterExecutionTaskExecuter.execute(SnapshotAfterExecutionTaskExecuter.java:38)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51) 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipCachedTaskExecuter.execute(SkipCachedTaskExecuter.java:101)  
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:49) 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:78)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:61)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)  
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91) 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:55) 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:35)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)   
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)    
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)    
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175) 
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)  
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)    
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:44) 
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)   
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)   
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)   
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)  
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)  
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134) 
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129) 
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)   
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)   
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)   
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)   
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)    
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)    
Caused by: com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.exceptions.ResolutionStackWrappingException: Exception in resolution, message is:   
Cannot resolve dependency:github.com/hashicorp/vic: commit='LATEST_COMMIT', urls=[https://github.com/hashicorp/vic.git, git@github.com:hashicorp/vic.git]   
Resolution stack is:    
+- github.com/streamsets/datacollector-edge 
 +- github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl#1e8e50f4f86c755c1a1147a929d9d51058f3bd1d    
  +- google.golang.org/grpc#b2ba77a36ff809ab344b98368d9ecc3e12f943d6    
   +- github.com/envoyproxy/go-control-plane#b51f8451dc7f3038dc909ad7fd5e12f58c0f3fb3   
    +- k8s.io/apimachinery#74be3b88bedbf44de881c8c33c5b1c3c536ad1f4 
     +- k8s.io/klog#f8e668dbaa5f6f0e6a5c24ffd7667263840d79ae    
      +- golang.org/x/exp#a2d0902c3ac7d8a588083a4600140f244aefee16  
       +- github.com/go-kit/kit#ab98ef03f368227b016c95423ee291c9812cae64    
        +- github.com/hashicorp/consul#bffdce7c1e2ffc3b7c753b506cd68c685a6a19d9 
         +- github.com/hashicorp/go-discover#c573d69da192ae69d5386b65b64353832677aad8   
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.exceptions.ResolutionStackWrappingException.wrapWithResolutionStack(ResolutionStackWrappingException.java:51)   
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeFactory.resolve(DependencyTreeFactory.java:93)    
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeFactory.getTree(DependencyTreeFactory.java:44)    
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.task.ResolveDependencies.resolveDependencies(ResolveDependencies.java:170)   
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.task.ResolveDependencies.resolve(ResolveDependencies.java:151)   
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)    
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48) 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:704)    
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:671)    
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:117)    
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)    
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)    
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175) 
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)  
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)    
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:106)    
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:85)    
    ... 37 more 
Caused by: com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.exceptions.DependencyResolutionException: Cannot resolve dependency:github.com/hashicorp/vic: commit='LATEST_COMMIT', urls=[https://github.com/hashicorp/vic.git, git@github.com:hashicorp/vic.git] 
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.exceptions.DependencyResolutionException.cannotResolveDependency(DependencyResolutionException.java:56) 
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.dependency.resolve.AbstractVcsDependencyManager.doResolve(AbstractVcsDependencyManager.java:73) 
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.dependency.resolve.CacheEnabledDependencyResolverMixin.lambda$resolve$0(CacheEnabledDependencyResolverMixin.java:38)    
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.cache.CloneBackedCache.get(CloneBackedCache.java:34)    
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.cache.ProjectCacheManager.resolve(ProjectCacheManager.java:57)  
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.dependency.resolve.CacheEnabledDependencyResolverMixin.resolve(CacheEnabledDependencyResolverMixin.java:36) 
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.vcs.git.GitNotationDependency.doResolve(GitNotationDependency.java:28)   
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.dependency.AbstractNotationDependency.resolve(AbstractNotationDependency.java:55)   
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeFactory.createSubContextAndResolve(DependencyTreeFactory.java:102)    
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeFactory.lambda$resolve$0(DependencyTreeFactory.java:90)   
    at com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.core.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeFactory.resolve(DependencyTreeFactory.java:91)    
    ... 54 more 
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Error in accessing https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/pkg/inflect, http response code: 404
```

How can gradle pick this library from local so that this api call is overlooked. As of now I am having the same package as forked and kept on local folder.

**UPDATE**:
The following code directly picks the same library:

```
go get bitbucket.org/pkg/inflect
```

So I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: your error is `Cannot resolve dependency:github.com/hashicorp/vic: commit='LATEST_COMMIT', urls=[https://github.com/hashicorp/vic.git, git@github.com:hashicorp/vic.git] ` Not sure that `LATEST_COMMIT` does mean anything in git. I guess `HEAD` is more appropriate. But IDK much about `gradle` and the java way to evaluate that output.